# Datacard as flashdrive?

Tags: storage

Can Datacard used as Flashdrive? If so what is the maximum memory it can be suggested.

Comment: Rolled back. [belongs-on-...] tags are discouraged; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4211

Comment: hmm, its not entirely clear what a datacard is, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @The Journeyman geek - I guess he means memory cards http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_card combined with some sort of usb reader. Only guessing though.

Comment: Well, that is a possibility, but its unclear. the answer would HEAVILY depend on the format and the planned use

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But most of the data cards has a lower data trasfer speed so it will take more time to copy a big file.